# Can the time to award a bounty by extended?

Tags: support

I have 20 hours to award a bounty on [one my questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161756/2464).

[One of the answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161891/2464) the question received is potentially acceptable, but this answer requires 3rd party software that is not installed on the system I'm using.

Therefore, I cannot immediately test/confirm that this answer solves my problem, and probably will not be able to within the next 20 hours<sup>1</sup>.

Is there a way to extend the time for awarding the bounty?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I have requested to get this software installed on said system, but the process of getting such installations approved and carried out is lengthy, especially with the holidays approaching.  I also looked into installing this software under my home directory, i.e. without admin privileges, but found several online discussions suggesting that such non-admin installations are difficult.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done. I have never seen it happen and if there was such a possibility, I guess it would be documented that e.g. mods could intervene.

The one thing I wouldn't do under any circumstances is to waste the bounty by not assigning it. The goal of this bounty was motivating users to look into the issue that otherwise no one would bother to look at because it is too hard or too local and needs effort. This is often the case with questions that have external dependencies like OS features or languages apart from Mathematica.

What I see is that Jason thought your situation through, found the possible duplicate and investigated to explain what is likely to be a solution. Be generous.

For me personally, it would leave a bad taste if I had investigated in a matter and I don't get the bounty when there are no other (reasonably) good answers. I am very sure that Jason is the last one who wouldn't help you further in case there is an issue with his solution.